# How to change MySQL datadir under debian9

Tags: mysql, debian

So i installed MySQL 8.0 on my dedicated debian 9 server.
As the server has a system volume of only 20G, i want to change the data directory to a second volume containing data. Mysql is running properly at this stage.

My second volume is mounter under "/mnt/web" (Ext4, just like the system volume)

I created a directory "/mnt/web/databases/mysql", and mysql user has RWX permissions on it.

Here is the steps i did :

- Stop mysql
- Change datadir in config file
- Create new directory, use ACL to give RWX permission to mysql (user + grp)
- Copy old directory content to new directory content
- Backup old directory content
- Restart mysql

It won't restart properly and i have these errors :

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-11-06 15:32:11 UTC; 2min 2s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 616 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 518 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 616 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "SERVER_BOOTING"
    Error: 13 (Permission denied)

Nov 06 15:32:11 ov-b6e882 mysqld[616]: 2018-11-06T15:32:11.541193Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 616
Nov 06 15:32:11 ov-b6e882 mysqld[616]: 2018-11-06T15:32:11.563003Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /mnt/web/databases/mysql/ov-b6e882.lower-test
Nov 06 15:32:11 ov-b6e882 mysqld[616]: 2018-11-06T15:32:11.563036Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /mnt/web/databases/mysql/ is case insensitive
Nov 06 15:32:11 ov-b6e882 mysqld[616]: 2018-11-06T15:32:11.563860Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010172] [Server] failed to set datadir to /mnt/web/databases/mysql/
Nov 06 15:32:11 ov-b6e882 mysqld[616]: 2018-11-06T15:32:11.563902Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
Nov 06 15:32:11 ov-b6e882 mysqld[616]: 2018-11-06T15:32:11.570248Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
Nov 06 15:32:11 ov-b6e882 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 06 15:32:11 ov-b6e882 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Nov 06 15:32:11 ov-b6e882 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 06 15:32:11 ov-b6e882 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I already did a lot of reasearch on forums, tried with mariadb too, restarted from the beginning 2 times, and still got at this point. Apparmor doesn't have a mysql profile and doesn't seem installed, i disabled it in the grub anyway to make sure, i really don't get where the problem is coming from.

I also tried to set up symbolic links from the old directory to the new one, didn't seem to work.

Am i missing something or doing anything wrong ? I'm really lost here and this seems to be an hard to solve common problem these days ...

Comment: "file system for /mnt/web/databases/mysql/ is case insensitive" - what filesystem is it? Have you tried on a different path? (different filesystem)

Comment: @symcbean it's formatted in ext4, just like the system volume, and no i didn't try a different path or filesystem, as it's exactly the same as it was in the first try with the server working. I mean, it's all ext4 with same permissions...

Don't get the case insensitive part though, might need an investigation, i just don't know where to start... Thanks for helping.